# menuitem wont work for ischecked property

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a menuitem to which i have included ischecked property. when a menu item is clicked it should keep on saving files and when menu item is not clicked it should overwrite the previous saved file.
clicking part is working but when it is not clicked it doesnt overwrite. The value of menuitem remains true all the times.

.xaml

```
 <MenuItem Header="Save" IsChecked="{Binding Saving ,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  >
```

.cs

```
 private bool saving =true;
    public bool Saving
    {
        get
        {
            return saving;
        }
        set
        {
            saving = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Saving");
        }
    }

 Configuration.isPrevSave = Saving;

 if (Configuration.isPrevSave == false && Configuration.PreviousFilePath != null && Directory.Exists(Configuration.PreviousFilePath))
                DirectoryInfo.DeleteContents(Configuration.PreviousFilePath);
            else //works
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the DataContext is correct you are only missing IsCheckable="True"

```
<MenuItem Header="Save" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Saving ,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Comment: Then the DataContext is wrong. Add a breakpoint to the set clause to check if it gets hit. As you didn't provide the full structure of your code i can't help with that other than saying if you declared that property correctly on the correct datacontext for the binding then it will work. Or i'm really not understanding your question.